# Change QML image cache size (QQuickImageProvider)

Tags: image, qt, caching, qml, qt5

**TL;DR:**
Is that possible to somehow change the caching properties in Qt so that images are cached for longer periods (indefinitely)?

**Whole question:**
I have Qt application that uses Qt5.7 or Qt5.9 (depending on the hardware where I run it).

Recently I've added support for [QQuickImageProviders](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qquickimageprovider.html) which I use to load an image in C++ and provide it to QML. One of the main reasons behind it was using image caching.

In one of my cases I have some kind of a "slideshow" in qml that requests an image in the background and when it's loaded- it swaps it with the current image (and repeats this continously).

What struck me is that when having 3 images in this slideshow: they are being cached after loading but after a couple of spins (next image is requested every 1 or 2 seconds) requested image is loaded from the hard disc and not from memory cache. This repeats, i.e. cache is being used for some time and then again images are loaded from the hard disc.

I've tried to search for some way of configuring this image cache but only found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8200605/clear-qml-image-cache) that threats about Qt4.7 and is not very helpful.

Comment: One possible 'overkill' method is to make your own ImageProvider. But this option is a lot of work for such a small thing.

Comment: @Velkan If I don't find anything- it is possible I'll be force to try this method. Have you tried it or do you have any tips to share?

Comment: I used it to get the textures from the game engine to the qml GUI. The engine owned all the textures and just handed their OpenGL IDs to the qml via `QQuickTextureFactory` and `QQuickImageProvider`.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?  I have the same problem

Comment: @PhillyTheThrilly - sorry, but no, I didn't find any solution.